# Binary Search Tree : no output

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I was making a binary search tree for my homework but it is not showing any output for **inorder**, **preorder** and **postorder** . Even though I am using `cout` in the `inorder` `preorder` and `postorder` functions yet it is not giving me any output. The error I feel is in `createBst` function yet I am not sure about it...kindly help me out
Thank You in advance :-)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*r;
struct node * createBst(struct node *r, int val)
{

    if (r == NULL)
    {
        r = new node;
        r->info = val;
        r->left = NULL;
        r->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (val <= r->info)
    {
        // cout<<r->left<<" ";
        r->left = createBst(r->left, val);

    }
    else
    {
        r->right = createBst(r->right, val);
        cout << r->right << " ";
    }
    return r;
}

void inOrder(struct node *r)
{
    if (r != NULL)
    {
        inOrder(r->left);
        cout << r->info;
        inOrder(r->right);
    }
}

void preOrder(struct node *r)
{
    if (r != NULL)
    {
        cout << r->info;
        preOrder(r->left);
        preOrder(r->right);
    }
}

void postOrder(struct node *r)
{
    if (r != NULL)
    {
        postOrder(r->left);
        postOrder(r->right);
        cout << r->info;
    }
}

int main()
{
    r = NULL;
    int n, val;
    cout << "Enter the number of element" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> val;
        //cout<<"check";
        createBst(r, val);
    }
    cout << "Inorder" << endl;
    //cout<<r->info<<endl;
    inOrder(r);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "PreOrder" << endl;
    preOrder(r);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "PostOrder" << endl;
    postOrder(r);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: _Not giving any output_ . This is a pretty vague statement. Are you receiving any errors on compiling ?? What's  IDE  are you are using to compile this ?

Answer (score 1):

In

```
createBst(r, val);
```

OP has not received the updated `r` back because the automatic variable `r` in

```
struct node * createBst(struct node *r, int val)
```

is not the same `r` as

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*r;
```

This can be fixed with

```
r = createBst(r, val);
```

or by changing the

```
struct node * createBst(struct node *r, int val)
```

to take the pointer by reference.

```
struct node * createBst(struct node * & r, int val)
```

Off topic, OP has set themselves up for some hilarious compiler and logic errors with `r` as a global variable and then using the variable name `r` extensively as an automatic variable in their functions. One typo and a clean "variable r not defined" message can get a whole lot messier.

And because not explaining how to fix that makes me an egotistical bastard who's just here to taunt "teh noobz," lose the `*r` here:

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*r;
```

and declare

```
node * r;
```

at the top of `main`. At the end of `main` I highly recommend iterating through the BST and `delete`ing all of the nodes to prevent the memory leak. I am enough of a sadistic torturer to not explain that one.

Comment: @ShaantamAnand Read the [**help tour**](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) describing how to use this site. Correct answers are credited by up-ticks and answer selection, neither of which you did. If you continue to not give credit where it is due, people will simply stop answering your questions.